# How to Upload an instance of File | Blob type to an object, on Google Cloud Storage Bucket - Object Storage

Tags: node.js

```
const storage = new Storage({ keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS! });
const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET_NAME!);
 
const uploadFile = async (folder: string, value: File | Blob, fileName: string ) => {
    try {
        await bucket.file(`${folder}/${fileName}`).save(value));

        return true;
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);

        return false;
    }
}
```

**What I want**

I want to be able to save a Video File (.mp4, etc) or Image File (.png, .jpeg, etc) on Google Cloud Storage, to retrieve later.

I am able to manually upload these files in Google Cloud Storage Console, and see them work as intended. So I understand this is possible to do.

The Video/Image File is uploaded via an HTMLInputElement, and then passed through a POST Request Body, to be passed to a Node JS backend. The code you see above takes the blob sent in the request body, to upload to Google Storage.

As you can see above, I attempt to save a Blob or File instance using the `.save()` method. This results in an INVALID_ARG_TYPE TypeError. As part of the details of this error, it tells me to convert the value type to a Buffer or Uint8Array.

**What's the correct upload method or object type I can use to store this on Google Cloud Storage?**

I've tried to convert the value to a Buffer Type. Doesn't upload.

```
await bucket.file(`${folder}/${fileName}`).save(Buffer.from(value)));
```

I've tried to convert the value to a Uint8Array Type. Uploads it, but the blob is question cannot be viewed, and the size is 0KB.

```
await bucket.file(`${folder}/${fileName}`).save(Uint8Array.from(value as any) as any);
```

The videos being tested are .mp4 files. Sizes are 770KB and 21.9MB (Testing two video files).

I'm using Node JS with the Package `@google-cloud/storage`. Referencing this example to try make this work - https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/HEAD/samples/uploadFromMemory.js